# Invalid conference data Error while replacing Zoom in Calendar Event with existing Google Meet using PATCH method

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have a Calendar Event which has Zoom meeting attached to it. The event JSON looks like this:

```
{
"created": "2024-01-31T11:06:52.000Z",
"updated": "2024-02-01T07:51:44.349Z",
"summary": "Sample Event",
"start": {
 "dateTime": "2024-02-01T18:00:00+02:00",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Tallinn"
},
"end": {
 "dateTime": "2024-02-01T19:00:00+02:00",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Tallinn"
},
"extendedProperties": {
 "private": {
  "meetingId": "xxxxxxxx",
  "zmMeetingNum": "xxxxxxxx",
  "meetingParams": "{\"topic\":\"Sample Event\",\"type\":2,\"start_time\":\"2024-02-01T18:00:00+02:00\",\"duration\":60,\"timezone\":\"Europe/Tallinn\",\"invitees_hash\":\"xxxxxxxx==\"}"
 }
},
"conferenceData": {
 "entryPoints": [
  {
   "entryPointType": "video",
   "uri": "https://company.zoom.us/xxxxxxxx",
   "label": "company.zoom.us/xxxxxxxx",
   "meetingCode": "xxxxxxxx",
   "passcode": "yyyyy"
  },
  {
   "regionCode": "US",
   "entryPointType": "phone",
   "uri": "tel:+zzzzzz,,cccccc#",
   "label": "+1 zzz-yyy-xxx",
   "passcode": "yyyyy"
  },
  {
   "entryPointType": "more",
   "uri": "some_uri"
  }
 ],
 "conferenceSolution": {
  "key": {
   "type": "addOn"
  },
  "name": "Zoom Meeting",
  "iconUri": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUkiyTEgH-6DiQP85RGtd_BORvAuFnS9katNMgwYQBJUTiDh12qtQxMJFWYH2Dj30hNsNUrr-kzKMl7jX-Qd0FR7JmVSx-Fhruf8xTPPI-wdsMYez6WJE7tz7KmqsORKBEnBTiILtMJXuMvphqKdB9X=s128-no"
 },
 "conferenceId": "xxxxxxxx",
 "parameters": {
  "addOnParameters": {
   "parameters": {
    "scriptId": "qwerasdfzxc",
    "realMeetingId": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "creatorUserId": "yyyyyyyyy",
    "meetingUuid": "zzzzzzzz==",
    "meetingType": "2",
    "originalEventId": "aaaaaaaaa"
   }
  }
 }
},
"reminders": {
 "useDefault": true
},
"eventType": "default"
}
```

Now, I am trying to change the conference data with existing Google Meet data using PATCH method but I am getting `Invalid conference data` error.
Body I am using on request:

```
{
"conferenceData": {
    "entryPoints": [
        {
            "entryPointType": "video",
            "uri": "https://meet.google.com/xxx-yyyy-zzz",
            "label": "meet.google.com/xxx-yyyy-zzz"
        }
    ],
    "conferenceSolution": {
        "key": {
            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
        }
    },
    "conferenceId": "xxx-yyyy-zzz"
    }
}
```

Couple of notes:

1. If I use `UPDATE` method, the request is successful, but my system is designed to use `PATCH` because I am not fetching the event before updating
2. If I have Google Meet as currently attached conference data and I want to do same thing and replace it with existing Zoom data, there request passes on `PATCH`

Comment: To clarify, what you'd like to do is use [`Events: patch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch) to change the video conferencing from `Zoom` to `Google Meet`. However, when you try it with the `Request body` that you have provided, you're getting the error `Invalid conference data`. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes @Saddles
That is exactly how you described.